# Unsure why my JavaScript FETCH call is failing, when the server returns HttpStatus 200 OK

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have an SPA client application that is doing a REST call to my localhost webserver. I'm using JavaScript to do the call and use `fetch()` to do this.

My response is an HttpStatus 200 (I can step through my webserver code AND confirm this with Chrome dev tools by looking at the XHR request/responses).

I'm doing an HTTP POST (to my web server)
The response is an HTTP 200 OK (not a 201 Created).

Before anyone starts to correct me on a POST returning a 200 -> this is a LOGIN/AUTHENTICATION endpoint, hence the 200, not 201.

So - is there a way I can figure out why fetch is doing this?

So when I use Chrome, the response says: `Failed to load response data`. BUT! if I do the same POST using (the program) **Postman** then I *do* get a response body...

Here's my code.

```
export function authenticateUser(idToken) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('idToken', idToken);

    fetch('https://localhost:44387/authentication',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => console.log("ok"))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

export function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}
```

[image][image]
[image]

- Added `handleErrors` code as requested.
- Added `Response` tab in Chrome dev tools

Comment: Can you show more code? what happens inside `handleErrors` function?

Comment: Is the browser logging any messages to the devtools console? Is this a cross-origin request? It's not a CORS issue?

Comment: @sideshowbarker No idea if this is a CORS issue. How can I check/tell? SPA app = (note: http) `http://localhost:3000/#` server = (note: https) `https://localhost:44387/authentication`

Comment: `response.ok` in handleError looks fishy. You are sure it contains what you think it contains? (For example, what you really are looking for may be in `response.data.ok` or similiar)

Comment: @ippi hmm. It goes _straight_ to line 164. Does go inside `handleErrors` .. ? Maybe I'm using `fetch()` incorrectly :~(

Comment: Show us the response tab

Comment: @Faris updated post again. So: Chrome `Response` tab says: `Failed to load response data` ??? while the program `Postman` correctly displays the response payload data.

Comment: By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server, 
if your api needs it, it will fail, try adding `credentials: 'include' `

Comment: Found the answer : t'was `CORS` :blush:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn - the answer was `CORS` :: I didn't have `CORS` setup on my webserver.

Clues:

- Using `Postman` to test my endpoint, it worked 100%
- @sideshowbarker 's comment suggesting me to question `CORS`.

A quick google search led me to [this simple explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api):

> Browser security prevents a web page from making AJAX requests to another domain. This restriction is called the same-origin policy, and prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. However, sometimes you might want to let other sites call your web API.
>
> Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a W3C standard that allows a server to relax the same-origin policy. Using CORS, a server can explicitly allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others.
>
> ---
>
> What is "Same Origin"?
>
> Two URLs have the same origin if they have identical schemes, hosts, and ports. (RFC 6454)
>   These two URLs have the same origin:
>
> - http://example.com/foo.html
> - http://example.com/bar.html
>
> These URLs have different origins than the previous two:
>
> - http://example.net - Different domain
> - http://example.com:9000/foo.html - Different port
> - https://example.com/foo.html - Different scheme
> - http://www.example.com/foo.html - Different subdomain

So in my scenario I have:

- Frontend / SPA: http://localhost:3000/
- Backend / REST endpoint: https://localhost:44387/authenticate

So what was diff?

- `Scheme` : `http` vs `https` <-- **different**
- `Host` : `localhost` vs `localhost` <-- same/ok
- `Port` : `3000` vs `44387` <-- **different**

so at least one of those three parts was diff, so I needed to enable `CORS` on my backend.

Once I did that, everything worked ok :)